# Extend existing class method

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Can I somehow extend existing class method from plugin? Or can I monitor output every time method get called?

There is

```
class greatPlugin{
...
  public function someProcess($vars){

    /* The magic */
    return $stringFromProcess;
  }
...
}
```

`greatPlugin` is called by hook inside WordPress before theme is loaded, but I need access (preferably) array of outputs generated by `someProcess` method. For example

`$greatSubOutput = array('string1', 'string2');`

or just `$greatSubOutput = null;` if method was not called.

The `greatPlugin` class is too complex to rebuild it's great work done by original dev. If I could add just some log2array feature to that function...

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the entire class, and then extend the method like so:

```
class loggingGreatPlugin extends greatPlugin 
{

    public function someProcess($vars) {
        $output = parent::someProcess($vars);

        $logger = new LogMe();
        $logger->log(LogLevel::INFO, $output);

        return $output;
    }
}
```